# Using armv7 and telephony in info plist failed app submission

Tags: ios, app-store, telephony, armv7, info.plist

Got this complaint after pressing the "Submit for Review" button,

[image]

What I really have is this

```
<<dict>
    <key>armv7</key>
    <true/>
    <key>telephony</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I have also tried the array format, ending up with same complaint. The [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) doesn't seem to show any thing wrong with my options.

**UPDATE**

I tried to remove the "armv7" key. With only "telephony", I got this complaint

[image]

So it turned out that iTunes connects does not like the **telephony** key.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these entries? Why do you have these two values as required device capabilities?

Comment: I want to submit an app only downloadable for iPhones because it requires phone functionality

Comment: It seems there is a mismatch in the app submission and the referenced document. Get rid of the `armv7` reference and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I bet it will work. But armv7 is an auto-generated option, a de facto choice. It would be surprising if it conflicts with telephony.